# How to add http headers to Apache Jena QueryEngineHTTP query?

Tags: rest, http-headers, jena

I'm trying to use HTTP headers so that I can authenticate my app to query ORCID (http://orcid.org) public API. I create the headers like this:

```
HttpOptions httpOptions = new HttpOptions();
Header contentTypeHeader = new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/orcid+json");
Header authorizationHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 5266384f-0567-43f0-9cd4-bc6f6a5dc3ea");
Header[] headers = new Header[2];
headers[1] = contentTypeHeader;
headers[2] = authorizationHeader;
httpOptions.setHeaders(headers);
```

but I don't know how to put these headers to my query. I'm writing my query like this:

```
QueryExecution execution = new QueryEngineHTTP(endpoint, query);
```

by using the org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena now (v3.1.1 and later) provides means to pass in an HttpClient with the necessary security setup.

[Docmentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/http-auth.html)

```
... set up an appropriate HttpClient for authentication ....

QueryExecution execution = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( ... , httpClient)
```